# Does a creature's enters the battlefield ability trigger if the creature is exiled in response?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was playing commander and played [Cultivator Colossus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cultivator%20Colossus) which says:

> Cultivator Colossus's power and toughness are each equal to the number of lands you control.
>
> When Cultivator Colossus enters the battlefield, you may put a land card from your hand onto the battlefield tapped. If you do, draw a card and repeat this process.

And as a response [Vanishing Verse](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Vanishing%20Verse) was played and that cards says:

> Exile target monocolored permanent.

The issue is that we don't know if the ability that says "when creature enters the battlefield" activates or not. Any help on this issue would be great.

Comment: I don't think so because the main difference is that for that post the triggered ability is due to tapping while in this case the ability triggers naturally. That was actually the question we looked at before asking this question I'd say that question answers this question partially but not fully.

Comment: @PandasINC The linked question isn't a triggered ability, it's an activated ability, however the rule that covers them is the same, removing the source after the ability is on stack does not stop the ability from resolving (and the ability goes on stack once it's triggered before they can cast spells in response to ETB)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cast cultivator colossus, and your opponent wants to use vanishing verse, they have to let the cultivator colossus resolve (and thus enter the battlefield) in order to stop being a "spell" and start being a "permanent".
Then we get into what Accumulation said; the ability is triggered, so if Cultivator Colossus is gone, the effect is already on the stack and isn't affected by its source being removed from the battlefield.

Answer (score 3):

ETB effects are triggered abilities. When the permanent enters the battlefield, the effect is put on the stack. The source of an effect being removed from the battlefield doesn't affect that effect, so you will still be able to put lands onto the battlefield.

> 113.7a Once activated or triggered, an ability exists on the stack independently of its source.
> Destruction or removal of the source after that time won’t affect the ability.